# Different led voltages for different colors

Tags: led

It's probably going to simple for someone to answer this one but I haven't done electronics in about 15 years now so please be kind with the answers

I'm sure when I used to do this there was an led you could get which would be different colours at different voltages but all I can find on a search is the household ones which are no good

I'm hoping for one that could run between 3v and approximately 5-6v

If not can someone point me towards some kind of circuit that could detect the change in voltage and activate a different circuit for different input voltages - even just read this would be great

Comment: A quick google search should yield results. Search multicolour LED. You'll likely find an RGB or RGBW LED. You can work out the colours from that easily. Next, you simply look up the voltage drop for each colour. Simple. This question should be easily answered with just a small bit of research effort on your part rather than asking it here and wanting us to do the work for you.

Comment: I do in electronics for about 15 years now (Ok, it's mainly SW development, but anyway!), and I don't understand what you actually want...? What are your requirements, if "household ones" are "no good"? An LED itself will not "be different colours at different voltages". An LED of a specific color needs a specific forward voltage for a specific current.

Comment: Hi Matthew do you mean a device/circuit that when you apply 3V you get one colour and when you apply 5V you get a different colour?  Do you need to choose the colours?

Comment: *an led you could get which would be different colours at different voltages* As far as I know such a product does not exist, OK, if you **overdrive** some LEDs they can change their color somewhat (like red to orange-red) but that is not "normal operation", the LED will be damaged if you do this for too long. Generally the color of a LED is determined by its chemical composition, that cannot be changed easily. A color changing LED must consist of several LEDs of different colors controlled by some electronics.

Comment: Hi johnathonjo that's probably the closest I mean, I wanted to do it so it's 1 colour at 3v another at 4v and another at 5v - I don't mind doing the research but I'm struggling with what to put into Google to search with as voltage detector turns up tools

Comment: I think I know what you mean now

Comment: @MatthewHill If you want a voltage dependent LED color, then how about searching for "voltage dependent LED color"? Google gives me this as first result: https://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4329054/Rainbow-LED-indicates-voltage-with-color It's an MCU based solution using an ADC input and three PWM outputs, which gives you maximum flexibility. But I'm sure there are simple "hardware only" solutions, too.

Comment: Since the OP is a new user, I don't think that the questions deserve **so much** downvotes (currently there are 4 downvotes). One or two would be enough. I'll upvote because of this. It is really the kind of question that should not be asked before searching in Google. The link provided by mic is a good start, but the article is very old (2004). I would use these search terms: "schematic', "battery gauge", "bargraph", "attiny" (I think that this uC should be used, its very simple, cheap, and can be programmed with an arduino and the Arduino IDE).

Answer (score 3):

Going by the comments, the goal OP has in mind is to have 3 different LED colours that will turn on at different voltages.

A way to do this is to use a comparator circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9FOts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So in this circuit, when Vin gets lower than Vref, the op-amp will output high and turn the LED on.

This should get your started towards coming up with your own circuit. A good beginners read on comparators can be found [HERE](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html) which goes through the types of comparator circuits and how to use them.

All you need to do is edit this circuit to do what you want. You can have multiple reference voltages at 2V, 3V, 4V, 5V and so on that toggle on different LEDs at different points.

You can either use multiple LEDs, use an RGB LED, or whatever you like. This answer should provide you with all the information you need to start designing your circuit, while not doing all the work for you.

Comment: Brilliant thank you now I know its a comparator circuit I can sit and have a good read down it

Comment: @MatthewHill No Problem. If you found the answer useful, don't forget to 'upvote' it. If it answers your question, then make sure to accept it as the correct answer (although usually people wait a while before accepting in case another person answers with something better) And lastly, try to edit your question slightly to make it easier to understand what it is you were wanting to do, without the comments, it was difficult to figure out what was being asked

Comment: I would replace R1 and R2 with much larger resistors, say in the 10K range.  They would still provide a stiff enough voltage at the +ve input of the op-amp without drawing so much current from the supply.

Comment: @MikeSpivey those were the default values the circuit designer gives you. I don't know his reference voltage so won't try to guess values, I'll leave as default.